# mysql query inside json foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, json, foreach

I'm trying to use a `json` file to import data to my `MySQL` table ... but the issue is that i guess i'm not able to do a query inside of the foreach loop.

is it possible to do a query inside of a `foreach` loop?

**EDIT:** I'm trying to run this code multiple times and not get duplicates ... but b/c the `$r_check` isn't working, it keeps duplicating entries ... i'm running 12k at a time of 100k+ of possible entries

here is my code:

```
$latest = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM prod_designs ORDER BY pd_modified_at ASC LIMIT 1"); 
$row_lat = mysqli_fetch_array($latest); 

$day = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($row_lat['pd_modified_at']));

$date = date_create($time);
date_add($date,date_interval_create_from_date_string("1 second"));
$new_time = date_format($date,"G:i:s");

$test_time = $day."T".$new_time."-05:00";

$str = file_get_contents('http://cdinternet.campdavid.com/Services/iPadDesignUtilities.asmx/GetDesignInfo?username=dew&password=Elv!s138&date='.$test_time.'&Structure=all&Max=12000');

$json = json_decode($str, true);

$count = count($json['designs']['images']);

$result = array();
foreach($json['designs']['images'] as $image) { 

    $name = $image['name'];
    $url = $image['url'];
    $created_at = $image['created-at'];
    $modified_at = $image['modified-at'];
    $img_mod_at = $image['image-modified-at'];
    $release_date = $image['release-date'];
    $desg_num = $image['design-number'];
    $desc = $image['description'];
    $top_selling = $image['top-selling'];
    $add_price = $image['additional-price'];
    $level_id = $image['level_id'];
    $place = $image['placement'];
    $designer = $image['designer'];
    $new_mod = $image['new-or-modified'];
    $style = $image['style'];
    $recco_for_style = $image['recommended-for-style'];
    $cust = $image['customer'];
    $protected = $image['protected'];
    $isdeleted = $image['isdeleted'];
    $isecda = $image['isecda'];
    $parent = $image['parent'];
    $notes = $image['notes'];
    $year = $image['year'];
    $div = $image['division'];
    $gender = $image['gender'];
    $location = $image['location'];
    $price_code = $image['price-code'];
    $keywords = $image['keywords'];
    $tags = $image['tags'];
    $category = $image['category'];
    $embellishment = $image['embellishment'];
    $trend = $image['trend'];

    $check = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT pd_name FROM prod_designs WHERE pd_name = '$name'"); 
    $r_check = mysqli_fetch_array($check); 

    if($r_check['pd_name'] != $name) {
        echo "Nope";
    } else {
       $insert = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO prod_designs (pd_name, pd_url, pd_created_at, pd_modified_at, pd_img_mod_at, pd_release_date, pd_desg_num, pd_desc, pd_top_selling, pd_gender, pd_price_code, pd_add_price, pd_embell, pd_level_id, pd_place, pd_designer, pd_year, pd_new_mod, pd_location, pd_style, pd_trend, pd_category, pd_recco_for_style, pd_div, pd_cust, pd_protected, pd_isdeleted, pd_isecda, pd_parent, pd_keywords, pd_tags, pd_notes ) VALUES ('$name', '$url', '$created_at', '$modified_at', '$img_mod_at', '$release_date', '$desg_num', '$desc', '$top_selling', '$gender', '$price_code', '$add_price', '$embellishment', '$level_id', '$place', '$designer', '$year', '$new_mod', '$location', '$style', '$trend', '$category', '$recco_for_style', '$div', '$cust', '$protected', '$isdeleted', '$isecda', '$parent', '$keywords', '$tags', '$notes')"); 

         if($insert) {
             echo "INSERTED<br>";
         }

     }

}
```

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly possible to execute SQL statements within loops. What output are you seeing? Is anything showing up in error logs?

Comment: Use prepared statements instead of concatenating all those values into your SQL. One of them probably has a `'` in it.

Comment: @cteski - no error logs, just not filtering out the entries ... i have a test file that i'm also running that is just echoing the results (rather than entering) and it just comes up blank

Comment: if there are no results, $r_check will be null and you'll immediately get an error

Comment: @GarrGodfrey - but i'm not getting an error ... that's the weird thing

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…”)` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: you aren't seeing an error, probably suppressed due to a php.ini setting.